# Change Bundle ID after upload a build in Itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am working with an app that was developed by another company, that later was rebuilt from scratch by the company where I am working on.

I need to change the bundle ID because refers the first corporation.

Itunes connect clearly describes the impossibility to change the Bundle ID of an app after uploading the app to itunnes connect.

For this reason I thought I could create a "New App" with exactly the same name in Itunnes connect and then, write the new bundle ID. In this manner, I would ignore the old app and starting to work in the new one.

The problem is that apple says something like when I tried to create a new app with almost the same information of the old one (except the bundle ID of course): 
"The name provided can not be the same of an existing app.."
 Which basically suggest that I need to contact apple to make a dispute with the "app owner" for legal issues related to comercial names and brands.

Now the problem is that We already are the owners of the other app, it is stupid to make dispute with ourselves.

How can I create a new app with the same app name of another app in the same Itunes connect account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your first app to something like `Your App Name: Some 
Description` and you will then be able to create `Your App Name` again.

If you first app has never been submitted to the App Store you may also be able to simply delete it.